# facebook apps works for the test accounts but not for the live accounts

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

my facebook application is working with the facebook test users accounts and permissions, facebook team reviewed the application and approved those permissions for the live app.

i am having a strange problem now, the application works fine with the facebook test accounts but not with the real accounts.

when i use the application with the live account i get this error.

```
Requires pages_read_engagement permission to manage the object {"exception":"[object] (Facebook\\Exceptions\\FacebookResponseException(code: 283): (#283) Requires pages_read_engagement permission to manage the object at /var/www/html/app/vendor/facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook/Exceptions/FacebookResponseException.php:137)
```

even though these permissions are already approved for the live accounts. i couldn't figure this out what is going on

Comment: Does Facebook's [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/pages_read_engagement/) not help? ... they mention needing: `This permission or feature is only available with business verification`, so do you have this level? ... but since you said `facebook team reviewed the application and approved those permissions` this may very likely be a question for Facebook's support.

Comment: Did the access token used have the pages_read_engagement permission?